# C# - AES encrypt-decrypt error : last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: c#, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string using AES everything. Everything work well when I'm using the same machine, but when I'm using different machine the, first to encrypt and another one to decrypt I have this error : last block incomplete in decryption.

This is my code :

public string Encrypt1(string plainText)

```
{
    string key = _appSettings.JwtSecret;
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] array;

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                }

                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
}

public string Decrypt1(string cipherText)
{
    string key = _appSettings.JwtSecret;
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
                {
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is somthing wrong with my code. I tryied many differents codes but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Are the keys identical on both machines? Post (non-productive) test data (key, plaintext, ciphertext). Post the .NET versions of the machines involved.

Comment: Side note: it's more efficient to use `return Convert.ToBase64String(array, 0, memoryStream.Length);` rather than using `ToArray`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with various .NET versions. The code follows the [MS pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0#examples) and is fine (the static IV is a security issue, but does not throw an exception). Most likely is corrupted or inconsistent data (e.g. different keys on the machines involved).

Answer (score 2):

Your example works fine for me using .Net framework 4.8.

However, you are using the initialization vector incorrectly. The IV should be *random* value, not just zeroes, but it is not *secret*, so it is fine to send this in clear text, for example prepended to the message:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    var input = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, 4096).Select(i => i.ToString()) );
    var str = Encrypt1(input);
    var result = Decrypt1(str);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, input);
}
public string Encrypt1(string plainText)
{
    byte[] array;
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = new byte[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,  12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
        var iv = aes.IV;
        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream( memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter( cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                }
                Assert.IsTrue(cryptoStream.HasFlushedFinalBlock);
                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
}

public string Decrypt1(string cipherText)
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            memoryStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
            aes.IV = iv;
            var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your error message suggest an issue with the final encryption block, possibly caused by an issue with disposing streams. The crypto stream needs to be disposed, or have an explicit call to [FlushFinalBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream_FlushFinalBlock) before the result is used. This *should* be done by `StreamWriter` when it is disposed, but I cannot find any documentation to confirm this, and it is possible that this could depend on the .net version.

I would suggest adding `Assert.IsTrue(cryptoStream.HasFlushedFinalBlock);` before `memoryStream.ToArray()`. If that fails you need to insert a call to `FlushFinalBlock`.

Comment: Shouldn't the underlying streams become *implicitly* [disposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.dispose?view=net-7.0) after leaving the `StreamWriter`-using block? After all the OP (apart from the variable names) uses the [MS pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0#examples) (which of course could also be buggy).

Comment: @Topaco, you are right, it should. The example works for me, so it is not impossible that there could be some version dependent issue. Updated the answer.